# Can’t start middleman server

Tags: ruby, gemfile, middleman

I Installed *middlemanapp*, and after trying to start a local server was asked to install **bundle**. I installed it and all was well.

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org’
gem 'nokogiri’
gem ‘rack’, '~> 2.0.1’
gem ‘rspec’
```

And when I enter *middleman server* I get the following error:

```
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/middleman-cli-4.2.1/bin/middleman:12:in require': cannot load such file -- dotenv (LoadError) from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/middleman-cli-4.2.1/bin/middleman:12:in<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/middleman:23:in load' from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/middleman:23:in’
```

What shall I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to reformat your question, rephrase it a little, and format your code. You can format text as code by indenting it by four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add middleman to your Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.4.2'

# For faster file watcher updates on Windows:
gem 'wdm', '~> 0.1.1', platforms: [:mswin, :mingw]

# windows does not come with time zone data
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mswin, :mingw]

# Middleman Gems
gem 'middleman', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.1'
gem 'middleman-livereload'

# Your Gems
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.1'
gem 'rack', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.3'

# Development
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec', '~> 3.7'
end
```

and run:

```
bundle install
```